# getting 405 when Post using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I need to do a POST request to an endpoint that requires
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
and bodyrequest with a JSON object

```
{
   "name":"name",
  "pw":"pw"
}
```

Now, when I use something like hurl.it or other tools it works just fine!
However, using $.ajax() all I CORS error!

I also noticed that the request turns into OPTIONS instead of POST! and the status code is 405 Method Not Allowed
And I can't seem to see the body anywhere!

Also, in the Request headers, I see things like
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

```
$.ajax({
     url: serverURI+'/login',
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     type: "POST",
     crossDomain: true,
     processData: false,
     dataType:'json',
     data: JSON.stringify({name:"name",pw:"pw"}),
     success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
     error: function(xhr, status, data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('Error: '+JSON.stringify(xhr) + 'ErrorStatus: '+JSON.stringify(status));
        }
});
```

The Error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://*/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

AND I have no access to the backend IIS server.

Comment: your server doesn't support cors it seems. OPTIONS call is a preflight request to check what is allowed  by the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
this call is supposed to return cors related headers to indicate browser what origins, methods, headers etc are allowed.

Comment: I told the backend but they keep getting back to me with working examples of all these tools which I don't know why they work fine!.